Doubt in showing the intersection of all sets in $F$ is nonempty
Question

Let $F = \{E_{1}, E_{2}, \ldots, E_{s}\}$ be a family of subsets with $r$ elements of some set $X$. Show that if the intersection of any $r+1$ (not necessarily distinct) sets in $F$ is nonempty, then the intersection of all sets in $F$ is nonempty.

Answer
Assume that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^s E_i=\varnothing$.
Consider a set $E_1=\{x_1, x_2,\dots, x_r\}$.
$x_1$ should not be in some of the sets.
Suppose $x_1\notin E_{k_1}$.
For every $x_i$, $x_i\notin E_{k_i}$ for some $i=1,2,\dots,r$.
Now we have a collection of $r+1$ sets $E_1, E_{k_1}, \dots, E_{k_r}$.
$E_1\cap E_{k_1}\cap \dots\cap E_{k_r}=\varnothing$.
Contradiction.
Now this is what I don't understand. What is the contradiction? The only thing I can see is, by contrapositive $E_1\cap E_{k_1}\cap \dots\cap E_{k_r}\ne\varnothing\implies\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^s E_i\ne\varnothing$.
What am I missing?

$E_1\cap E_{k_1}\cap \dots\cap E_{k_r}=\varnothing$ contradicts the premise that "the intersection of any $r+1$ sets in $F$ is nonempty".

@Karl but the assumption was that the intersection is empty, wasn't it?

You assumed for the sake of contradiction that the intersection of all the sets in $F$ is empty. This doesn't mean the intersection of a smaller collection is empty.

Yes, but we neither assumed the intersection of any $r+1$ sets in $F$ is empty nor nonempty. So it wasn't a premise for the arguments.

It is given: "Show that if the intersection of any r+1 (not necessarily distinct) sets in F is nonempty, then ..."

@Karl so you mean that 'the intersection of any r+1 sets in F is nonempty' is a given fact? I thought of it as a condition. Like, if  then the intersection of all the sets is nonempty.

@Jarvis Think about it like this. Let $P$ denote the statement "the intersection of any $r + 1$ sets in $F$ is nonempty". Let $Q$ denote the statement "the intersection of all sets in $F$ is nonempty". The "proof by contradiction" assumes $P$ as given. Then, it shows that $\neg Q$ leads to $\neg P$, the contradiction, so it must be that $Q$. You can see how this is just proof by contrapositive.

To prove "if P then Q" you can assume P and deduce Q.

Thanks for the help.

You can consider it as a proof of the contrapositive. What the proof shows is that, given $\bigcap_{i = 1}^s E_i$ is empty, there is some collection of sets $E_{m_1}, \dots, E_{m_{r + 1}}$, not necessarily distinct, whose intersection is also empty. This was done by letting $m_1 = 1$, and, assuming that $E_1 = \{ x_{1}, \dots, x_{r} \}$, picking for each $j \in \{1, \dots, r\}$ a $m_{j + 1}$ such that $E_{m_{j + 1}}$ misses $x_j \in E_1$.
The contrapositive of the above statement is: if every collection of $r + 1$ sets (not necessarily distinct) has non-empty intersection, then the intersection of all the sets is non-empty, which was to be shown.

So there was no contradiction regarding the assumption? (Also if possible, can you please review my last comment below the question?)

Right, I think it is a bit misleading by saying "contradiction" when in essence it is just the contrapositive that is being proved. Of course, if we are trying to show that $P \implies Q$, we could assume $P$ as a hypothesis and show that the proposition $\neg Q$ leads to a contradiction, i.e., $\neg P \land P$ (which is what I think the answer you showed is trying to do). But this is nothing more than $\neg Q \implies \neg P$ (the contrapositive).

Thank you for the edit. Yes, indeed I meant $\bigcap$, not $\bigcup$.
